# java.lang.NullPointerException when I tried create EntityManager with transaction-type="JTA"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need use `transaction-type="JTA"` type in my persistence-unit

I have this config:

```
<persistence-unit name="COLIBRI" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>shiro.entety.User</class>
        <class>avaya.entety.AvayaSdr</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://....;DatabaseName=sp"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="..."/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="..."/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And I have this classes:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import java.util.List;

public interface BaseDao<E> {

    E persist(E e);

    E get(Long id);

    List<E> getAll();

    E merge(E e);

    E refresh(E e);

    void remove(E e);

    void remove(Long id);

    void saveAll(List<E> entityList);

    void flush();

    Session getSession();
    EntityTransaction getEntityTransaction();
    EntityManager getEntityManager();
}
```

And

```
public abstract class BaseJpaDao<E> implements BaseDao<E> {

    protected Class<?> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "COLIBRI")
    private EntityManager em;

    public BaseJpaDao(Class<?> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public E persist(E e) {
        em.persist(e);
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public E get(Long id) {
        return (E) em.find(entityClass, id);
    }
```

...

After that I create Dao interface:

```
public interface AvayaDao extends BaseDao<AvayaSdr> {

    List<AvayaSdr> getAll();
    void insertCdr(AvayaSdr avayaSdr);
}
```

And DaoJpa:

```
public class AvayaJpaDao extends BaseJpaDao<AvayaSdr> implements AvayaDao {
private static AvayaJpaDao instance;
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

public AvayaJpaDao() {
    super(AvayaSdr.class);
}

@Override
public List<AvayaSdr> getAll() {
    return super.getAll();
}


public synchronized static AvayaJpaDao me() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new AvayaJpaDao();
    }
    return instance;
}


public void insertCdr(AvayaSdr avayaCmCdr) {
    persist(avayaCmCdr);
}
```

}

But when I called

```
List<AvayaSdr> resultList = AvayaJpaDao.me().getAll();
```

I have an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I found how use JTA [this](http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html)

And I tried make like this:

```
@Stateless
public class AvayaJpaDao extends BaseJpaDao<AvayaSdr> implements AvayaDao {
```

But in my `public abstract class BaseJpaDao<E> implements BaseDao<E> {`

highlight how wrong `BaseJpaDao`
I dont understend how create `JTA` and `EntityManager` with annotation

Comment: Posting the full stacktrace would help.

Comment: That has nothing to do with JTA. You expect the container to inject the entity manager in an object you create yourself, using new. That won't happen. The container only injects the objects it creates itself. Use dependency injection, instead of creating AvayaJpaDao yourself.